# Simple proof involving eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space for
>   which every non-zero vector is an eigenvector. Prove that $T$ is a
>   multiplication by a scalar.

Firstly, if this question was asking to prove the converse "If $T$ is multiplication by a scalar, then every non-zero vector is an eigenvector" then it's clearly true, but in trying to show the above I'm finding it hard to prove rigorously. Clearly, for any non-zero vector $v$ we have that

$T(v) = \lambda v$ for some scalar $\lambda$ (the eigenvalue) and I don't really know where to go from here, partially because I think I'm finished (I mean, we've shown that $T$ just multiplies a vector by some scalar) but given how I've come to this conclusion in literally one step, I'm thinking I've simplified the question or assumed something I shouldn't have.

Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I think you should prove that the scalar is unique. So far you know that for every $v$ there exists $\lambda_{v}$, ie. a scalar that depends on $v$, such that $T(v)=\lambda_v v$. In other words, proving that for any $x,y$ in the vector space you have $\lambda_x=\lambda_y$ should finish the proof.

Comment: In order to show that $T$ is multiplication by a scalar, you need to show that $\lambda$ is the same for any vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ be a basis. Then $Tv_i=\lambda_i v_i$  for some $\lambda_i$.

Also, $T(v_1+v_2+\cdots+v_n)=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda$. It follows that
$$(\lambda_1-\lambda)v_1+ (\lambda_2-\lambda)v_2+ \cdots+(\lambda_n-\lambda)v_n=0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the concise solution!

Comment: You are welcome. I left a bit for you to do. It is clear that you saw how the rest of the argument goes.

Comment: Yeah, as soon as the comments mentioned I need to show that all the eigenvalues are the same it clicked. Since all the $v_i$ are non-zero and linearly independent we have that all the coefficients must be zero which implies $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = ... = \lambda_n = \lambda$.