# Prove that this bilinear form is symmetric or skew-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

There's this bilinear form $f$ such that $\forall x, y \in V \ \ f(x, y) = 0 \implies f(y, x) = 0$. What I need to prove is that this form is symmetric or skew-symmetric.

I don't understand how to approach this. I've tried adding something like $f(x - x, y)$ (which equals to $0$) and such to $f(x, y)$, and then applying the property above to the result, but didn't get anything. I've also tried looking at $f(x, y) - f(y, x)$ and something like $f(x + y - y, y)$, hoping I'd get some revelation if I try to transform these expressions in various ways, but to no avail.

Comment: The correct statement would be "Prove that $f$ is symmetric or skew-symmetric".

Comment: is $V$ finite-dimensional ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon the statement (as I know it) says nothing on this. Should I add this to the question?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Take, for instance $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by$$f\bigl((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\bigr)=x_1y_2-x_2y_1.$$Then $f(v,w)=0\iff f(w,v)=0$, but $f$ is *not* symmetric.

Comment: Any non trivial skew-symmetric form is a counterexample.

Comment: @Gribouillis I now, but I thought that a concrete example would be better.

Comment: Oh, of course, thank you very much, I fixed the question.

Comment: @wouldnotliketo By fixing it, you turned a question that makes sense into one that doesn't.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean. There's a bilinear form of a known property. I need to prove that it is either symmetric or skew-symmetric, as you and other users have pointed out that it could be skew-symmetric. Why does this not make sense?

Comment: @wouldnotliketo Because $\forall x,y\in V\ f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ means that $f$ is symmetric, not that it is symmetric or skew-symetric, which is what you wrote right after. Anyway, you will find an answer to your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656213/bilinear-form-with-symmetric-perpendicular-relation-is-either-symmetric-or-ske).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you very much for your corrections, I have edited the question again; and thank you for the provided link. However, I'd like to keep the question open because I'm interested in other proofs (if it's possible to prove this any other way), since I'm unfamiliar with the fundamental theorem of linear algebra, for example, thus I'm unable to fully understand the given, although great and seemingly very detailed, proof.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what about the infinite dimensional setting ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon I don't know the answer.